# script to kill process with specific character

Tags: linux, script, process, kill

I have a command that outputs as follows:

```
# lostjobs

user1   12983     1  0 Feb04 ?        00:00:00 dbr UT:msmenu
user1   18253     1  0 Feb09 ?        00:00:00 dbr UT:msmenu
user2   22337     1  0 Feb09 ?        00:00:00 dbr UT:msmenu
user3   7164   7123  0 06:52 pts/0    00:00:10 dbr UT:msmenu
```

I know I can grab the ones with what I want to kill (which are the ones with question marks) with:

```
# lostjobs | grep ?
```

what I need to know is how can I loop through the results of the second one and kill them by id (the second column).  I am not great with writing scripts for linux, so go easy on me.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is:

```
kill `lostjobs | awk '{ if ( $6 == "?" ) print $2 }'`
```

Comment: and that will kill all of them?

Comment: That will execute: `kill 12983 18253 22337`. Try to prefix the command with `echo` to see a preview.

Comment: ok, to kill the users, we have to use -9, so I assume I can just do kill -9 `lostjobs |...

Comment: Sure, add whatever option you like to `kill`.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
kill -9 `lostjobs | grep ? | awk {'print $2'}`
```